# Can Taigam grant rebound to spells I already cast before his attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, for example, if I cast Shock, and then during my combat step attack with [Taigam, Ojutai Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTaigam%2c%20Ojutai%20Master%5d), then after he attacks, cast another spell like Opt, would both Shock and Opt gain rebound as they were cast on a turn that the creature attacked? Or only Opt as it was cast after he attacked?

Answer (score 3):

It would only count instants or sorceries that you cast after Taigam attacks.

Taigam's ability only triggers at the time that you cast an instant or sorcery, and at that moment it checks to see if he has attacked that turn. Each time you cast an instant or sorcery, his ability triggers if he has attacked that turn. Any instants or sorceries you cast when he hasn’t attacked that turn don’t meet the requirements for triggering.

Note that Taigam's triggered ability has an intervening if clause:

> 603.4. A triggered ability may read “When/Whenever/At [trigger event], if [condition], [effect].” When the trigger event occurs, the ability checks whether the stated condition is true. The ability triggers only if it is; otherwise it does nothing. If the ability triggers, it checks the stated condition again as it resolves. If the condition isn’t true at that time, the ability is removed from the stack and does nothing. Note that this mirrors the check for legal targets. This rule is referred to as the “intervening ‘if’ clause” rule.

This means that when you cast an instant or sorcery spell, if he hasn’t attacked this turn, the ability doesn’t trigger at all. But even if it were not an intervening if clause (such as “whenever you cast an instant spell, it gains rebound if Taigam has attacked this turn), then the ability still wouldn’t work in that case. It would trigger and go on the stack, but when it resolved it would have no effect because the condition wouldn’t be met.

In order to affect instants and sorceries that were cast before attacking, it would have to have a completely different wording; such as something that triggers when he attacks instead of triggering when you cast the spell.

Comment: "It would only count instants that you cast after Taigam attacks." Instants or sorceries.

Comment: @Acccumulation Fixed.

Answer (score -2):

https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Rebound

> From the Comprehensive Rules (July 3, 2020—Core Set 2021)
> 702.87. Rebound
> 702.87a Rebound appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents a static ability that **functions while the spell is on the stack** and may create a delayed triggered ability. “Rebound” means “If this spell was cast from your hand, instead of putting it into your graveyard as it resolves, exile it and, at the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast this card from exile without paying its mana cost.”
> 702.87b Casting a spell as an effect of its rebound ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.
> 702.87c Multiple instances of rebound on the same spell are redundant.

[bolding added]

Once the spell resolves, it's not on the stack anymore (and in fact does not exist as a spell anymore). Since it's not on the stack, rebound doesn't apply. There's also the fact that when an object changes zones, it becomes a new object with no memory of the previous one. When a spell resolves it leaves the stack and enters the graveyard, and once in the graveyard it has no "memory" of being a spell that was cast on a turn that Taigam attacked.

Comment: I don’t see how this addresses the question. How rebound works doesn’t seem relevant at all; the question was whether the triggered ability would grant rebound in the first place. The question could be the same with a different ability that did something other than granting rebound (with the same triggering condition).